# Display date and time according to the user's time zone in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, timezone, cfml

I need to display datetime values in my application according to the logged in user's local timezone. I would like my app to be able to detect the user's timezone automatically then display the adjusted server date and time accordingly.

How do you do this in Coldfusion?

I am looking for a solution that does NOT prompt the user to select their time zone at any point, like Facebook.

Thanks

Comment: Generally you can only determine the users timezone offset, and this cannot account for DST. You could attempt to use IP geolocation but this is generally not specific enough in Australia (users in Broken Hill will geo-locate to Sydney, and do not share the timezone). At some point I'm pretty sure you will find a corner case where you need to ask the user. Better to just render dates client side (assuming users have setup their computer correctly!)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of having CF do the formatting, I would push a standardized date representation (like UTF( and have JavaScript format the date.  That way, the date is formatted to whatever timezone is set on the computer.

This avoids wrong lookups near zone change areas, dealing with daylight savings vs. areas where it isn't observed, and people traveling (formatting to "home time" vs. "local time").

**Added:**

This dumps the current time in a long format.  It's semi-off-the-cuff, so you'll want to look at the [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)'s methods for more formatting options.

```
<cfset n = dateconvert("local2utc",now())>
<script>
 d = new Date();
 d.setUTCFullYear(#dateformat(n, "yyyy")#);
 d.setUTCMonth(#dateformat(n, "m")#);
 d.setUTCDate(#dateformat(n, "d")#);
 d.setUTCHours(#timeformat(n, "H")#);
 d.setUTCMinutes(#timeformat(n, "m")#);
 document.write(d.toLocaleString());
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ben - could you perhaps provide some example code about what you mean?? Thanks

Comment: Don't forget the javascript has months numbered 0 - 11 so this `d.setUTCMonth(#dateformat(n, "m")#);` should be `d.setUTCMonth(#dateformat(n, "m")# - 1);` for javascript to show the correct month.

Answer (score 6):

ColdFusion is a server side language. So you can't determine the timezone of a client in a direct way.

You can use JavaSript on the client side, find out the timezoneoffset and send it via an Ajax request to ColdFusion.

JavaScript:

```
var clienttime = new Date();
var time = clienttime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

Then on the server side you can use the offset to calculate the date you want to show the user.

You can also lookup the country of the client using the client IP, but then you have to use an external service to get the country for a certain IP and you have to deal with problems like daylight savings and multiple timezones per country.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quicker and more accurate if you did just ask your user to specify their timezone as part of their login profile; set once and forget.

Otherwise, you're looking at doing an IP address look up and determining where that IP address is based, determining the timezone and then displaying the time accordingly. Even if you store the information in a cookie or session variable, its a bit of a faff when you could just ask your user what timezone they are in.

Comment: Well yes and no. I am aiming at looking up the timezone by IP when the user registers. So it's once off. Yes, I could ask for it - but my question clearly states does NOT prompt the user. Asking a user to select a timezone is too technical. They are laymen, not developers :)

Comment: In which case you'll need access to a commercial geocoding api such as maxmind (http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location), after which you'll have to determine the users timezone from the city using something like Paul Hasting's tzmap on riaforge : http://tzmap.riaforge.org/

Comment: I have to say though, wow that's a tough crowd you've got there if they don't know their own timezone. ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that there is also the issue of Daylight/Standard time. So when it is DST you'll have to subtract an hour from the timezone offset. Also, DST does not start and end at the same time everywhere. So basically what I would do is record their current timezone offset as a session variable, and recalculate it based on their city after each login. That way, you don't have to worry quite as much.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using cfwheels.org and your users doesnt mind to see "yesterday" or "10 minutes ago"... then the TimeAgoInWords() is what you need.